# how to convert p tag to line break in php fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have the following for setting up the body of my fpdf:

```
function PrintChapter($num, $title, $date,$url,$Summery,$file,$byauthor){
        $this->AddPage();

        $this->SetDate(date("l F d, Y",strtotime($date)));

        $this->Main_Full_TITLE($title);
        //$this->PrintMainTitle("1",$title);
        if($url){
            $this->ChapterImage_H_W($url);
        }else{

            if($Summery){
                $this->y0 = $this->GetY()-13;
            }else{
                $this->y0 = $this->GetY()-30;
            }
        }
        $this->ChapterHead($Summery,$byauthor);
        //$this->ChapterTitle($num,$title);
        $this->ChapterBody($file);

    }

function ChapterBody($file){
        $txt = $file;
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',12);
        $this->MultiCell(92,5,$txt);
        $this->Ln();
        if($this->col==0){
            $this->Line(10, $this->GetY(), 100, $this->GetY());
        } else {
            $this->Line($this->GetX(), $this->GetY(), $this->GetX()+90, $this->GetY());
        }
        $this->Ln();
    }

$pdf->PrintChapter(1,$title,$PostData['post_date'],$url[0],$Summery,$MyContent,@implode(", ",$BYAuthorName));
```

The problem, is that my paragraphs do not have a big enough line space between and don't look like line breaks at all.  How can I make the line breaks more distinct to show more paragraph formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an individual height to the [Ln()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/ln.htm) method. If nothing is passed the last height of a cell is used. Which is `5` in your case (defined as 2nd parameter of the [MultiCell()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm) call).

You can control the line height/height of a line break with both parameters.